# Cardano-cli query utxo fails

Tags: blockchain, cardano

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeLNI.png) I am trying to create a staking pool for cardano, i got the node up and running but cardano-cli is giving me a hard time. I have it installed as when i type cardano-cli version it returns info[cardano-cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iysZ9.png).

However when i enter cardano-cli query utxo --mainnet --address $RECEIVER i get this error:

cardano-cli: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: does not exist (No such file or directory)root@vmi803461:~#

Could it be because the blockchain isn't fully synched?

I am running windows 10 with vs

[node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRhkg.png)

Comment: Hi, hopefully you already found the answer, but, for future people that asked the same. It's probably because the cardano-node isn't running **at the same time** you do cardano-cli. I was having same issue before, but I realize we need to make cardano-run on the background, so the generated "network socket" can be used for cardano-cli

Comment: Yes, now it works i just had to wait for the blockchain to sync.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ivan p is correct however its also important to mention that there have been cardano node example scripts involving stakepools such as creating a shelley blockchain from scratch that had a bug for quite some time essentially causing multiple nodes to point to the same socket. If you're attempting to run multiple nodes - which you should be while running a stakepool, double check the precise path and location of the socket

Answer (score 0):

`cardano-cli` requires both `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` variables installed in the shell and node server running to access it with the socket.

`export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH="/root/db/node.socket"`

> To query the balance of an address we need a running node and the
> environment variable CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH set to the path of the
> node.socket: